# Declaring Array of pointer to template functions gives compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I am trying to store a bunch of templated function pointer in an array to function pointer.

i tried

```
template<typename T> 
void (*funcptrArray[100])(typename vector<T> &a,int,int,bool (*comp)(T,T));
```

it gives compilation error in g++

> ** Error expected primary expression before template**

EDIT:
What i am trying to achieve here is:
Given  10 different algorithms (templated function), for same task.I Want to store different instantiations in array so that I can iterate and run them one by one in a loop

Comment: @Kerrek SB No typedef here

Comment: As it stands, your question makes no sense. A "function pointer" is an object, and objects have types. A template is not a type (it's a *template*.) You can't have a "templated object".

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of function pointers that can refer to different template instantiations?

Comment: @greatWolf Yes this is what i exactly want to do

Comment: @David you know you can't do that because each instantiation is considered a different type of function. An array has to be homogeneous.

Comment: @Kerrek SB. So what is the best way to do this? if you have 10 different algorithms (templated function).whose intantiation you want to store in an array so that you can iterate and run them one by one.

Comment: @David varadic templates might be a solution here if you can use C++11. Pass in the list of types to instantiate with to a varadic function and have it instantiate and call your algorithm for each one.

Comment: Can you edit your post to describe a representative, minimal, *realistic* situation? I think we're stabbing in the dark a little too much here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only create class or function templates. There is no such thing as a variable templates, yet (there was talk about doing something like that, though). One work-around is to use a class template providing access to the array instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct func_ptr {
    static void (*array[100])(std::vector<T>&, int, int, bool (*)(T, T);
};

template <typename T>
void (*func_ptr<T>::array[100])(std::vector<T>&, int, int, bool (*)(T, T);
```

This should work but isn't too scalable. Wrapping the array into a function template and returning a reference to the array will work better: This way it is easy to get just one instance of the array as `static` variable in function templates need to be merged between different instantiations with the same parameters. Writing out the return type of the function template is just a bit awkward:

```
template <typename T>
void (*(&funcPtrArray())[100])(std::vector<T>&, int, int, bool (*)(T, T))
{
    static void (*array[100])(std::vector<T>&, int, int, bool (*)(T, T));
    return array;
}
```

I was wondering if C++11 helps but it doesn't:

```
auto funcPtrArray() -> void (*(&)[100])(std::vector<T>&, int, int, bool (*)(T, T))
{
    ...
}
```

You would then use the function to get you the array, e.g.:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
funcPtrArray<int>()[12](vec, 1, 1, [](int a, int b){ return a < b; });
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. I still don't understand if you can have the array of function template wrapped inside a function why can't you have it without a wrapper?

Comment: @David: Conceptually, it would work but currently you only templatize functions and classes. As I said, there was talk about creating variable templates. I could also imagine `enum class` templates (e.g., to set the values of certain members) and namespace templates (everything within is templatized on the namespace's type). However, none of these things are currently allowed.

Comment: @David note this is not an array of function templates in the sense you are looking to use like in your earlier comment. This creates an array of func ptrs to one particular instance of `T`. For example, you  create 100 func ptrs that can only refer to functions taking a vector of ints. You cannot for example, assign a function taking `vector<foobar>` as parameter and store it into this array.

Comment: @Dietmar, if i have to assign two different function to funcPtrArray how can i do that? imagine i have qsort(vector<int> v, int start,int end,bool (*comp)(int,int)), and mergesort(vector<int> v, int start,int end,bool (*comp)(int,int)) which you want to store in the array pointer

Comment: @David: Well, you'd assign to the array elements instead of calling them: `funcPtrArray<int>()[0] = qsort; funcPtrArray<int>()[1] = mergesort;`

Comment: @greatWolf,I agree with your comments that you can't mix function taking the vector<int> with vector<foo> parameter, but it allows me to store set of function which are taking vector<int> in one func array (wrapped by class) and another set of function taking vector<foo> in another function array. This will do for me. For example, if you want to execute various sorting methods in a data set and see the run time behavior, you can all store it in one array to function pointer. (my application is executing various tempalated method in a graph and trying to find quantify the quality of results.